# Probability of second drawn balls

Tags: probability

Suppose that we have 10 balls numbered 1 through 10. Four balls are drawn without replacement.

What is the probability that the second largest number drawn will be 6?

I can't find the favorable outcomes.
Any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: How many possible selections of $4$ balls are there out of $10$? How many of those selections have one ball numbered $1$ through $5$, one ball numbered $6$, and the remaining two balls numbered $7$ through $10$?

Comment: so first one is clear and it's $\left( \begin{array}{cc}
10\\
4\\
\end{array} \right) $
but is it true to say our favorable out comes are $\left( \begin{array}{cc}
9\\
4\\
\end{array} \right) $ * $\left( \begin{array}{cc}
5\\
5\\
\end{array} \right) $ * $\left( \begin{array}{cc}
4\\
1\\
\end{array} \right) $ * $\left( \begin{array}{cc}
5\\
2\\
\end{array} \right) $

 i think its wrong :) i don't know how to select these balls?

Comment: The favorable outcomes are outcomes, what you wrote was a number, so first note that the number you gave is an attempt to count the number of favorable outcomes, but not the favorable outcomes themselves. Your counting isn't quite right since there are $5$ balls numbered $1$ through $5$, so you have ${{5}\choose{1}}$ ways to pick that one, there is one ball labeled $6$, so you have ${{1}\choose{1}}$ way to pick that one,...

Comment: the second largest number is 6 !so the first number is between 7-10 and two others are between 1-5.
so we have ${{4}\choose{1}}$ for 7-10 ,${{5}\choose{2}}$ for 1-5 and ${{1}\choose{1}}$ for 6 so the answer is ${{4}\choose{1}}*{{5}\choose{2}}*{{1}\choose{1}}/{{10}\choose{4}}$ am i right?

Comment: @user3682067 If 'second largest number' means that exactly one of the drawn balls has a higher number than $6$ then you are correct. In this answer deals with the case that exactly $2$ of the drawn balls have a higher number than $6$.

Comment: @user3682067 You're correct, I have my interpretation backwards.. I was thinking "ranking" rather than numeric value. Though, the method should be analogous.